# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" while saving to database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to add new room, I would type the room details, `Room Number, Room type, Bed number and Rates` into the text fields, when I click save, I get the error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

The error originates from `at RoomMang.jButton1ActionPerformed(RoomMang.java:352)` which is `fetchFromTextF();` function. See Image : [image: RoomMgt]

My insert statement using `System.out.println (insertquery);` looks like this:
`insert into roomdetail(room_no,room_type,room_rate,room_bed)values('','','','');`

This is how i fetch the data from the textfields:

```
public void fetchFromTextF(){
    rno=rnumber.getText();
    rtype=jTextField2.getText();
    rrate=Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
    rbed=jTextField4.getText();
}
```

And this is my save action performed button:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        clearTextF();
        enableTextF();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM roomdetail where room_no like '" +           rnumber.getText() + "';";
        smt = con.createStatement();
        rs1 = smt.executeQuery(query);
        if (!rs1.next()) {
            try {
                if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("Save")) {
                    fetchFromTextF();
                    int code = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Information of Room No." +rno+ " will be added in database.", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    if (code == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        String insertquery = "insert into roomdetail(room_no,room_type,room_rate,room_bed)values('" +rno + "','" + rtype + "'," + rrate + ",'" + rbed + "');";
                        smt = con.createStatement();
                        int success = smt.executeUpdate(insertquery);
                        if (success > 0) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Saved");
                            jButton1.setText("New");
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Problem in Saving. Retry");
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                } else if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("New")) {
                    clearTextF();
                    jButton1.setText("Save");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Room No. already used, Give another Room No.");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: show your stacktrace so that we can see where it happens.  Although I guess it happens on *that* sql insert that you have.  Use a PreparedStatement to avoid these errors and possible sql injection attacks  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 1):

The value in `jTextField3` is blank so the below will fail

```
rrate=Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
```

maybe change to

```
rrate = -1;
if (jTextField3.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
  rrate=Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
}
```

or simply catch the exception

```
try {
   rrate=Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText().trim ());
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.err.println (ex);
    rrate = -1;
}
```

Comment: That has not worked, it has only saved the ``-1`` value to the database, the rest are blank in the db. Its like no values are being saved to the database, all goes as empty values

Comment: So, all of your textfields are empty (as processed by fetchFromTextF)

Comment: add `System.out.println (insertquery);` to show your insert statement

Comment: This is my statement ``insert into roomdetail(room_no,room_type,room_rate,room_bed)values('','',-1,'');``

Comment: so as you can see, there are no values being retrieved from `fetchFromTextF` except for the code that I have already fixed for you.  I can not tell from the lack of code that you have posted why this is.  Are these textFields being defined in multiple places?